# Calculating binding energies for excitated levels in potassium?

Tags: ions, spectroscopy, orbitals

Suppose a laser is used to excite electronic transitions in potassium from the $3p$ orbitals to ones higher than $4s$. When I attempt to use the Bohr model to calculate binding energies, what I obtain for $n\le4$ disagrees significantly with [this source](http://xdb.lbl.gov/Section1/Table_1-1.pdf), calling into doubt my results for $n>4$. I think it might be possible to use the [Rydberg formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rydberg_atom#Quantum-mechanical_details), but I'm having trouble finding a working example that computes the right energies; in addition, there is [another form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_defect#Quantum_defect_in_Rydberg_atoms), and the two seem inconsistent.  How does one calculate the binding and transition energies in potassium for levels $n>4$? Are the quantum defects for arbitrary elements available online?

What changes here if we're talking not about pure potassium but potassium chloride?

Comment: Perhaps relevant: http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/32350/can-the-bohr-atomic-model-be-applied-to-sodium-and-other-single-valence-electron

Comment: What do you expect by using the Victorian technology (Bohr model)? :) More than a century ago Bohr himself attempted to use his model to calculate energy levels in many-electron atoms and quickly found that it gives unacceptable numbers already for the lightest of then, $\ce{He}$ atom. For the next couple of decades after this discovery a scientific thought in that area had developed revolutionary and a good physical theory that gives way better predictions for atomic energy levels (amongst many other things) was formulated.

Comment: Fair enough. :)  But my problem is a practical one, and it would be nice to have realistic transition energies, so that I will know what photon wavelengths are needed to excite the transitions.  Any help is appreciated.